# Loading ASP user control dynamically looses javascript line breaks

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am loading an asp.net user control from a web method. But the javascript no longer has any line breaks when debugging with Firebug or Chrome. Is there a way to preserve the line breaks?

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadUserControl(string message)

{
    using (Page page = new Page())
    {
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl("Message.ascx");
        (userControl.FindControl("lblMessage") as Label).Text = message;
        page.Controls.Add(userControl);
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            page.Controls.Add(userControl);
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```